# What does "put custard mixture over heat" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

Could anyone tell me the meaning of "put something over heat"? Does it mean reheat something? Is "put something over heat" a kind of phrasal verb? It's from a recipe in a cookbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not a phrasal verb.

The words have their usual meanings: 
put (place) 
something 
over (above) 
heat (something that makes heat, like a flame or an electric burner)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common construction that means apply heat, generally from a fixed source below the object. Often that means apply heat in a pan on a stove when cooking. It can be used by mechanics to describe heating parts with a blowtorch and many other ways and many English speakers will understand it.